# If protons(positive charges) also flow in a circuit, do we say that a conductor has free protons?

Tags: electrostatics

This might be a stupid question, but it is logical. We say that even protons or positive charge can flow to constitute current. But, protons are present inside the nucleus of an atom. So, when we say that protons flow, are the atoms of the conductor moving(atoms here refer to ions)? Is it not inappropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current constituted by positive ions doesn't imply that the current is constituted by protons. The positive charge might also be constituted by ions, or holes in semiconductors. If you are referring specifically to a circuit made up of solid material, then protons are tightly bound and hence don't flow and positive charge if any, is due to holes. Protons might constitute a current when voltage is applied across an ionized sample of hydrogen gas but in general positive charge doesn't mean only protons, it can refer to ions or holes too.

Comment: And to add fun, band structure can do fun things even in metals - as pointed out by Ashcroft and Mermin, the high-field Hall coefficient in aluminum is positive - holes (in a metal!) are carrying the current in that situation.

Comment: @JonCuster thanks for the info..wasn't aware of that..will look it up..

Comment: A naked proton _is_ a cation.  I think what you are trying to say is that protons are not the _only_ cations that can carry current.  As for "holes", they may be a useful abstraction when explaining how semiconductors work, but they aren't physical particles.  The physical particles that move  in a current-carrying, P-type semiconductor are electrons.

Comment: @jameslarge you are right about holes.. the physical particles are definitely electrons and i don't dispute that.. but that was an important point to be included so i included it..as for naked protons, i have specifically mentioned 'ions' in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When we say proton flow it means H+ flow and by charge flow it may be H+ or any other ion.